# MVC 2 application failing because of System.Web.Mobile assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a legacy web application which currently utilizes MVC 2, it fails to load at run time due to it trying to load System.Web.Mobile 4.0.0.0 and failing.  I can't find any projects our solutions referencing that assembly, and the Fusion bind log shows the following:

```
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ReportViewer/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ReportViewer\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reportviewer\46e43c05
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reportviewer\46e43c05
LOG: AppName = 709d1cbc
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
```

I've tried forcing the specific version to 2.0.0.0, copying the dll locally on publish... adding the specific version in the web.config file.

Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.